# Why JavaScript array is repeating after add canvas.addEventListener() for onclick event on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have showing some images on canvas using JavaScript. Also I have generate on-Click event on canvas using `canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown, false);` .

If I put alert an array before `canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown, false);` then fine but 
But when I put alert an array in Mouse_Down() then it showing Previous with current array in alert.

All above code is re-execute on menu change.

JavaScript Code is -

```
var Image_Array = [];
for (i = 0; i < Values.length; i++) {
    Image_Array.push(image_data[i]);
}
alert(Image_Array); // is showing fine
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", Mouse_Down, false);

function Mouse_Down(event) {
    // here is problem means array showing previous and current array value.
    alert(Image_Array);
}
```

Above all code execute on menu change.
Please help.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle please.

Comment: What is `Mouse_Down`? `Mouse_Down !== doMouseDown`.

Comment: Mouse_Down() is function